# How to pass an array of array of floats to C++ function from swift

Tags: c++, arrays, swift

I have a C++ function declared in `Bridging-Header.h`

```
struct MyFloat3{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
struct MyFloat3 ExtCurl(const float** triangle);
```

I have followed the instructions at http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html
wrapper.cpp

```
#include "Curl.h"
extern "C" MyFloat3 ExtCurl(const float** triangle){
    return Curl(triangle);
}
```

Curl.h

```
struct MyFloat3{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
MyFloat3 Curl(const float** triangle);
```

Curl.cpp

```
#include "Curl.h"
MyFloat3 Curl(const float** triangle){
  MyFloat3 curl;
  curl.x = (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][2]) - (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]);
  curl.y = (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][0]-triangle[0][0]) - (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][2]);
  curl.z = (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]) - (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][0]-triangle[0][0]);
  return curl;
}
```

I tried to call it from my swift code

```
var triangle:[[Float]] = [
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.8],
            [0.0, 0.5, 0.0],
            [4.0, 0.0, 6.0]
        ]
var normal:MyFloat3
normal = ExtCurl(triangle)
```

Compiler scolds

```
Node.swift:127:38: Cannot convert value of type '[[Float]]' to
expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Float>?>!'
```

An another function of my C++ library which returns void but fills an array through the pointer given to it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let triangle0: [[Float]] = [
    [1,2,3],
    [10,20,30],
    [100,200,300]]

let normal = triangle0.flatMap{ $0 }.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (buffer) -> float3 in
    var p = buffer.baseAddress
    return ExtCurl(&p)
}
```

update to see the difference (for OOPer)

```
let triangle:[Float] = [
    1.0, 0.0, 0.8,
    0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
    4.0, 0.0, 6.0
] 
let normal = triangle.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (buffer) -> float3 in
    var p = buffer.baseAddress
    return ExtCurl(&p)
}
```

UPDATE with working example (Swift, C++)//

main.swift

```
var triangle:[[Float]] = [
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.8],
    [0.0, 0.5, 0.0],
    [4.0, 0.0, 6.0]
]

triangle.flatMap{ $0 }.withUnsafeBufferPointer {(buffer)->() in
    var p = buffer.baseAddress
    let normal = fc(&p)
    print("from Swift:", normal)
}
```

tempt-Bridging-Header.h

```
struct float3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct float3 fc(const float **);
```

test2.hpp

```
#ifndef test2_hpp
#define test2_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

struct float3CPP {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct float3CPP fcpp(const float **);

extern "C" struct float3CPP fc(const float ** p) {
    return fcpp(p);
};

#endif /* test2_hpp */
```

test2.cpp

```
#include "test2.hpp"

struct float3CPP fcpp(const float ** triangle) {
    float3CPP curl;
    curl.z = (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]) - (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][0]-triangle[0][0]);
    curl.y = (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]) - (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][0]);
    curl.x = (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][2]) - (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]);
    return curl;
}
```

it prints

```
from Swift: float3(x: 111856.898, y: -3.65359902e+24, z: 3.86805511e+24)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

as expected ...

please check the values in triangle[x][y] ... there are not what you would like to see there :-)

so your only trouble is how to convert float **p to t[3][3]

```
struct float3CPP fcpp(const float **t) {

    float triangle[3][3];
    for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        int row = i / 3;
        int col = i % 3;
        triangle[row][col] = *(*t + i);
    };


    float3CPP curl;

    curl.z = (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]) - (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][0]-triangle[0][0]);
    curl.y = (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]) - (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][0]);
    curl.x = (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][2]) - (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]);


    return curl;
}
```

will return you the wanted

```
from Swift: float3(x: 2.5999999, y: 5.0, z: -1.5)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

UPDATE 2
if you define c++ function as

```
struct float3CPP fcpp2(float triangle[3][3]) {

    float3CPP curl;

    curl.z = (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]) - (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][0]-triangle[0][0]);
    curl.y = (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]) - (triangle[1][0] - triangle[0][0])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][0]);
    curl.x = (triangle[1][1] - triangle[0][1])*(triangle[2][2]-triangle[0][2]) - (triangle[1][2] - triangle[0][2])*(triangle[2][1]-triangle[0][1]);

    return curl;
};
```

your c++ header file will be

```
struct float3CPP fcpp2(float t[3][3]);
extern "C" struct float3CPP fc2(float t[3][3]) {
    return fcpp2(t);
};
```

with bridging header

```
struct float3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct float3 fc2(float [][3]);
```

and main swift

```
let triangle:[[Float]] = [
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.8],
    [0.0, 0.5, 0.0],
    [4.0, 0.0, 6.0]
]

var t2 = triangle.reduce([]) { (r, row) -> [(Float, Float, Float)] in
    var r = r
    r.append((row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    return r
}

t2.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (buffer) -> () in
    var p = buffer.baseAddress
    let normal = fc2(p)
    print("from Swift fc2:", normal)
}
```

prints correct result

```
from Swift fc2: float3(x: 2.5999999, y: 5.0, z: -1.5)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**UPDATE 3** the "best" way, how to do it, is to
declare c++ function as

```
// parameter is pointer to array of array 3 of const float
struct float3CPP fcpp3(const float (* const t)[][3]) {
    return fcpp2(*t);
}
```

update your headers .... and use it from Swift

```
let triangle:[[Float]] = [
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.8],
    [0.0, 0.5, 0.0],
    [4.0, 0.0, 6.0]
]
triangle.flatMap{ $0 }.withUnsafeBufferPointer {(buffer)->() in
    let normal3 = fc3(OpaquePointer(buffer.baseAddress))
    print("from Swift fc3:", normal)
}
```

prints the right result :-)

```
from Swift fc3: float3(x: 2.5999999, y: 5.0, z: -1.5)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: It's another possible interpretation of passing _array of array_ to `const float**`. Mine passes a pointer to 3 pointers, each points to 3 Floats. Yours passes a pointer to a pointer which points 9 Floats. Which works properly, mine or yours, depends on how `ExtCurl` treats the argument. I do not know anything about the implementation of `ExtCurl`, do you know something about it?

Comment: @OOPer please see my update with your data (triangle). in both cases, yours or mines, the only parameter passed to c function is &buffer.baseAddress. try it, please ... you could also write var p = [buffer.baseAddress] ... nothing will change.

Comment: Seen. The difference still exists. Your code passes a pointer to a single pointer. My code passes a pointer to a 3-pointer array. I do not know which is the right one, but they are different. Think of a C-code like `triangle[i][j]`, your code does not work when i == 1 or i == 2.

Comment: @OOPer the c function see const float **  .... nothing else! there is no guarantee, how the c function will process it. that is, why word Unsafe is part of the name (withUnsafeBufferPointer).

Comment: Do I need to repeat? _I do not know which is the right one_ Your code may work or mine may work. But I need to say the two codes generate different results. Your code is not just a shortcut or a refined version of my code.

Comment: @OOPer :-) you don't need to repeat. you have to check, that what c function received will be the same const float **. It is very easy to do it and is not necessary to discuss it more. by the way,  c defined float_arr[1][3] could not  by passed as a parameter to as float **. you have to allocate first float **p = malloc(sizeof(float)); and next  *p = &arr[1][0]; p could be passed to our c function.

Comment: So, what? Why do you explain a fact that I know very well?

Comment: Can I access `float3` members by `normal.x, normal.y, normal.z`?

Comment: @neckTwi https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html see Structures there

Comment: It seems working but the C++ implementation is returning wrong values **Swift:** `[-0.0116278976, 0.0, -0.0116279041]`
**C++:** `MyFloat3(x: 4.03136313e+34, y: -4.03137055e+34, z: -inf))`

Comment: @neckTwi check http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html#step3 (sorry, I didn't check you are talking about C++)

Comment: Thats what I followed. I don't have any problem with an another function of my C++ library.

Comment: @neckTwi hard to say, I suggest writing some very simple test C++ function with the same signature which returns very well defined value (float3 struct) and using the debugger. I did it, and it works ok for me. my function returns first three floats received via float ** filled in float3 struct. works as expected.

Comment: @neckTwi and see this http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/diab5.0ppc/c-additi.htm#3000472 if it still doesn't work for you

Comment: @neckTwi http://choruscode.blogspot.sk/2012/04/struct-member-alignment-errors.html

Comment: The another function that is working returns void but fills an array through the pointer given to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143646/discussion-between-user3441734-and-necktwi).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, it's not easy to work with nested C-arrays which are represented by pointer to pointer. As the expected type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Float>?>!` is suggesting, you need to create an array of `UnsafePointer<Float>?`, and pass the pointer to the array.

In your case, something like this:

```
let triangle:[Float] = [
    1.0, 0.0, 0.8,
    0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
    4.0, 0.0, 6.0
]

var normal = triangle.withUnsafeBufferPointer {(buffer)->MyFloat3 in
    let rowCount = 3
    var rowPointers: [UnsafePointer<Float>?] = [
        buffer.baseAddress,
        buffer.baseAddress!+rowCount,
        buffer.baseAddress!+rowCount*2
    ]
    return ExtCurl(&rowPointers)
}
```

(Assuming your `ExtCurl` does not keep the pointers for future use.)

Comment: you don't need to use rowCount ... &rowPointers has to point to buffer.baseAddres, the rest of your array is never used. see my answer

Comment: It seems working but the C++ implementation is returning wrong values **Swift:** `[-0.0116278976, 0.0, -0.0116279041]`
**C++:** `MyFloat3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0))`

Comment: @neckTwi, Can you show me how you call your function in C++?

Comment: @neckTwi, Seems you have some mistakes to run my code and your C++ code. My code above shows `MyFloat3(x: 2.5999999, y: 5.0, z: -1.5)` **without any modifications** to your cpp codes, which should be the right result.