# How to transfer array?

Tags: swift, objective-c++

**Introduction:**

I'm using a `objc++ to Swift` bridge where I implemented a delegate to Swift like:

```
func callback(_ myCallbackValue: String!) {
   print(myCallbackValue);       
}
```

and a `objc++` function that does a callback like:

```
[self.delegate myCallbackInstance: myCallbackValue];
```

---

**Some example code**:

The callback using simple Types like `"String", "int" or "double"` is working fine - but I got big problems to callback 2d-arrays (from c++ vectors) like :

```
(objc++) vector<vector<String>>    ->    (swift) [[String]]
```

e.g. **c++:**

```
vector<vector<String>>myVector = { {"1", "dh", "o4"}, {"2", "5", "1"} };
```

to **swift**:

```
let myCallback : [[Sting]] = ?? // should get [ ["1", "dh", "o4"], ["2", "5", "1"] ]
```

**My quesion**:

> How can I implement this specific callback the right way?

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: vector in c++ isn't an array, i suppose same true for objc++

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of this but I'd like to convert the `2d-vector` to `an array` in @Swift

Comment: By "convert", I presume you mean put the information from the std::vector into an NSArray.  You'll have to write that convert routine yourself, std::vector does not bridge to NSArray.  Swift does not interop directly with C++.  Alternative is to make an interface that Swift can use to manipulate the std::vector on the C++ side.

Comment: Maybe, try using `std::vector::data`. This returns a raw pointer to a C-array. Swift *should* be able to handle those.

Comment: @Clearer I will! somehow. *ahem* this might be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810486/how-to-pass-an-array-of-array-of-floats-to-c-function-from-swift

Comment: My work is done!