# Turn an array of array of float numbers into UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c, swift, unsafemutablepointer

I need to use a function that uses `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!` as a parameter. It's written in a framework in Objective-C++ and I'm accessing it through a bridging header:

```
- (void) applyFilters: (float *) input_image input_params: (long *) input_params output_image : (float *) output_image output_params : (long *) output_params filter_id : (int) filter_id args : (float**) args
```

I'm having some trouble understanding the structure of the args parameter, which is `float**`. In Swift, it asks for a parameter of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>`, which I'm guessing points to an array of array of floats.

```swift
applyFilters(input_image: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>!UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>!, input_params: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>!, output_image: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>!, output_params: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>!, filter_id: Int32, args: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>!)
```

If I create an array of array of floats, how do I point to it using `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>` so I can pass it to a C++ function?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810486/how-to-pass-an-array-of-array-of-floats-to-c-function-from-swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it:

```swift
func arrayOfArrayExample() {

    let floatArray: [[Float]] = [
        [50.0, 23.0, 15.6],
        [24.0, 9.5, 12.7]
    ]

    let size1 = floatArray.count
    let size2 = floatArray[0].count

    var vectorBuf : UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?
    let bufferOut = UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>.allocate(capacity: Int(size1))

    for i in 0..<size1 {
        vectorBuf = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: size2)
        for j in 0..<size2 {
            vectorBuf!.advanced(by: j).pointee = floatArray[i][j]
        }
        bufferOut.advanced(by: i).pointee = vectorBuf
    }

    defer {
        //deallocating memory
        for i in 0..<size1 {
            bufferOut.advanced(by: i).deallocate()
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `bufferOut` returns an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>` pointer that points to an array of array of Float, deallocating memory afterwards.